# How to fix java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException image resizing error?

Tags: java, image, resize, overflow

I have little experience with java programming, but I know my way around it a little. I want to pick up a project that was left behind by someone else. I was doing well fixing other errors here and there, but this one stumped me. Here it is:

```
javax.imageio.IIOException: Can't read input file!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at Replacer.main(Replacer.java:19)
```

To my surprise, the program still opened. However, when I tried to open a picture, this happened, and displayed a picture of 0 x 0 pixels:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:
 2147483647
        at ImageEditor.resize(ImageEditor.java:384)
        at ImageEditor.resize(ImageEditor.java:308)
        at ImageFrame.setImage(ImageFrame.java:438)
        at ImageFrame.actionPerformed(ImageFrame.java:765)
        at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionP
rivilege(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Replacer:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.PrintStream;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Replacer
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    BufferedImage i = null;
    BufferedImage i2 = null;

    Color[][] blockColors = new Color[16][16];

    ImageFrame b = new ImageFrame(i);
    try
    {
      i2 = ImageIO.read(new File("terrain.png"));
      int blockSize = i2.getWidth(b) / 16;
      System.out.println("Analyzing terrain.png");
      int[] buffer = ImageEditor.returnBuffer(i2, b);
      int width = i2.getWidth(b);
      for (int j = 0; j < 16; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 16; k++) {
          if ((j <= 2) || (k <= 8))
          {
            int[] i3 = ImageEditor.crop(buffer, width, width, b, j * blockSize, k * blockSize, blockSize, blockSize);
            blockColors[j][k] = ImageEditor.getAverageColor(i3, b);
          }
        }
      }
      Color[] c2 = new Color[100];
      c2[0] = blockColors[1][8];
      c2[1] = blockColors[2][10];
      c2[2] = blockColors[1][11];
      c2[3] = blockColors[1][9];
      c2[4] = blockColors[1][7];
      c2[5] = blockColors[0][4];
      c2[6] = blockColors[2][13];
      c2[7] = blockColors[1][13];
      c2[8] = blockColors[1][12];
      c2[9] = blockColors[2][7];
      c2[10] = blockColors[2][11];
      c2[11] = blockColors[2][8];
      c2[12] = blockColors[2][9];
      c2[13] = blockColors[2][12];
      c2[14] = blockColors[1][14];
      c2[15] = blockColors[1][10];

      c2[16] = blockColors[1][0];
      c2[17] = blockColors[2][0];
      c2[18] = blockColors[2][1];
      c2[19] = blockColors[3][1];
      c2[20] = blockColors[8][4];
      c2[21] = blockColors[5][2];
      c2[22] = blockColors[4][2];
      c2[23] = blockColors[6][7];
      c2[24] = blockColors[4][0];
      c2[25] = blockColors[0][1];
      c2[26] = blockColors[0][11];
      c2[27] = blockColors[7][0];
      c2[28] = blockColors[6][1];
      c2[29] = blockColors[7][1];
      c2[30] = blockColors[8][1];
      c2[31] = blockColors[0][9];
      c2[32] = blockColors[10][4];
      c2[33] = blockColors[9][6];
      c2[34] = blockColors[7][6];
      c2[35] = blockColors[8][6];
      c2[36] = blockColors[2][4];

      c2[37] = blockColors[6][3];
      c2[38] = blockColors[1][1];
      c2[39] = blockColors[5][1];
      c2[40] = blockColors[4][1];
      c2[41] = blockColors[4][7];
      c2[42] = blockColors[5][7];
      c2[43] = blockColors[0][3];
      c2[44] = blockColors[3][4];
      c2[45] = blockColors[8][8];
      c2[46] = blockColors[8][9];
      c2[47] = blockColors[8][10];
      c2[48] = blockColors[8][11];
      c2[49] = blockColors[8][12];

      for (int j = 0; j < c2.length / 2; j++)
      {
        double shadowRed = 0.892D * c2[j].getRed() + 0.5D;
        double shadowGreen = 0.892D * c2[j].getGreen() + 0.5D;
        double shadowBlue = 0.892D * c2[j].getBlue() + 0.5D;

        c2[(50 + j)] = new Color((int)shadowRed, (int)shadowGreen, (int)shadowBlue);
      }
      for (int j = 0; j < c2.length; j++) {
        System.out.println("colors[" + j + "] = new Color(" + c2[j].getRed() + "," + c2[j].getGreen() + "," + c2[j].getBlue() + ");");
      }
      b.setColors(c2);
      System.out.println("Done");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    b.repaint();
  }
}
```

ImageEditor:

```
    import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.MediaTracker;
import java.awt.image.MemoryImageSource;
import java.awt.image.PixelGrabber;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class ImageEditor
{
  public static int[] returnBuffer(Image i, Component c)
  {
    MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(c);
    tracker.addImage(i, 0);
    try
    {
      tracker.waitForAll();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      System.out.println("Image loading interrupted");
    }
    int width = i.getWidth(c);
    int height = i.getHeight(c);

    int[] buffer = new int[width * height];

    PixelGrabber grabber = new PixelGrabber(i, 0, 0, width, height, buffer, 0, width);
    try
    {
      grabber.grabPixels();
    }
    catch (InterruptedException e)
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return buffer;
  }

  public static Image simplifyColors(int width, int height, int[] buffer, Component c, Color[] colors)
  {
    double[] w = new double[colors.length];
    for (int k = 0; k < w.length; k++) {
      w[k] = 1.0D;
    }
    return simplifyColors(width, height, buffer, c, colors, w);
  }

  public static Image simplifyColors(int width, int height, int[] buffer, Component c, Color[] colors, double[] weights)
  {
    int[] simple = new int[buffer.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length; j++)
    {
      int minDiff = 10000000;
      Color current = new Color(buffer[j], true);
      Color col = Color.black;
      for (int k = 0; k < colors.length; k++)
      {
        Color test = colors[k];
        double w = weights[k];
        if (test != null)
        {
          int diff = (int)((Math.pow(test.getRed() - current.getRed(), 2.0D) + Math.pow(test.getGreen() - current.getGreen(), 2.0D) + Math.pow(test.getBlue() - current.getBlue(), 2.0D)) / w);
          if (diff < minDiff)
          {
            col = test;
            minDiff = diff;
          }
        }
      }
      if (current.getAlpha() >= 128) {
        simple[j] = col.getRGB();
      } else {
        simple[j] = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0).getRGB();
      }
    }
    return c.createImage(new MemoryImageSource(width, height, simple, 0, width));
  }

  public static Image simplifyColors2(Image i, int[] buffer, Component c, Color[] colors)
  {
    double[] w = new double[colors.length];
    for (int k = 0; k < w.length; k++) {
      w[k] = 1.0D;
    }
    return simplifyColors2(i, buffer, c, colors, w);
  }

  public static Image simplifyColors2(Image i, int[] buffer, Component c, Color[] colors, double[] weights)
  {
    int height = i.getHeight(c);
    int width = i.getWidth(c);
    int[] simple = new int[buffer.length];
    float[] hsb1 = new float[3];
    float[] hsb2 = new float[3];
    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length; j++)
    {
      int minDiff = 10000000;
      Color current = new Color(buffer[j], true);
      hsb1 = Color.RGBtoHSB(current.getRed(), current.getGreen(), current.getBlue(), null);
      Color col = Color.black;
      for (int k = 0; k < colors.length; k++)
      {
        Color test = colors[k];
        if (test != null)
        {
          hsb2 = Color.RGBtoHSB(test.getRed(), test.getGreen(), test.getBlue(), null);
          int diff = (int)(Math.pow(hsb1[0] - hsb2[0], 2.0D) + Math.pow(hsb1[1] - hsb2[1], 2.0D) + Math.pow(hsb1[2] - hsb2[2], 2.0D));
          if (diff < minDiff)
          {
            col = test;
            minDiff = diff;
          }
        }
      }
      if (current.getAlpha() >= 128) {
        simple[j] = col.getRGB();
      } else {
        simple[j] = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0).getRGB();
      }
    }
    return c.createImage(new MemoryImageSource(width, height, simple, 0, width));
  }

  public static Image simplifyColors3(int width, int height, int[] buffer2, Component c, Color[] colors, double[] weights)
  {
    int[] buffer = (int[])buffer2.clone();
    int[] simple = new int[buffer.length];
    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length; j++)
    {
      int minDiff = 10000000;
      Color current = new Color(buffer[j], true);
      Color col = Color.black;
      for (int k = 0; k < colors.length; k++)
      {
        if (current.getAlpha() == 0)
        {
          col = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0);
          break;
        }
        Color test = colors[k];
        double w = weights[k];
        if (test != null)
        {
          int diff = (int)((Math.pow(test.getRed() - current.getRed(), 2.0D) + Math.pow(test.getGreen() - current.getGreen(), 2.0D) + Math.pow(test.getBlue() - current.getBlue(), 2.0D)) / w);
          if (diff < minDiff)
          {
            col = test;
            minDiff = diff;
          }
        }
      }
      int quantErrorR = current.getRed() - col.getRed();
      int quantErrorG = current.getGreen() - col.getGreen();
      int quantErrorB = current.getBlue() - col.getBlue();
      if ((j + 1) % width != 0)
      {
        Color x = new Color(buffer[(j + 1)], true);
        Color y = new Color(Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getRed() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorR * 7 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getGreen() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorG * 7 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getBlue() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorB * 7 / 16, 255)), x.getAlpha());
        buffer[(j + 1)] = y.getRGB();
      }
      if (((j - 1) % width != 0) && (j - 1 + width < buffer.length))
      {
        Color x = new Color(buffer[(j - 1 + width)], true);
        Color y = new Color(Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getRed() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorR * 3 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getGreen() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorG * 3 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getBlue() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorB * 3 / 16, 255)), x.getAlpha());
        buffer[(j - 1 + width)] = y.getRGB();
      }
      if (j + width < buffer.length)
      {
        Color x = new Color(buffer[(j + width)], true);
        Color y = new Color(Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getRed() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorR * 5 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getGreen() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorG * 5 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getBlue() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorB * 5 / 16, 255)), x.getAlpha());
        buffer[(j + width)] = y.getRGB();
      }
      if (((j + 1) % width != 0) && (j + 1 + width < buffer.length))
      {
        Color x = new Color(buffer[(j + 1 + width)], true);
        Color y = new Color(Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getRed() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorR * 1 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getGreen() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorG * 1 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getBlue() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorB * 1 / 16, 255)), x.getAlpha());
        buffer[(j + 1 + width)] = y.getRGB();
      }
      if (current.getAlpha() >= 128) {
        simple[j] = col.getRGB();
      } else {
        simple[j] = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0).getRGB();
      }
    }
    return c.createImage(new MemoryImageSource(width, height, simple, 0, width));
  }

  public static Image shadowColors(int width, int height, int[] buffer, Component c, Color[] colors, double[] weights)
  {
    int[] simple = new int[buffer.length];
    double k2 = 0.0D;
    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length; j++)
    {
      int minDiff = 10000000;
      Color current = new Color(buffer[j], true);
      Color col = Color.black;
      for (int k = 0; k < colors.length; k++)
      {
        Color test = colors[k];
        double w = weights[k];
        if (test != null)
        {
          int diff = (int)((Math.pow(test.getRed() - current.getRed(), 2.0D) + Math.pow(test.getGreen() - current.getGreen(), 2.0D) + Math.pow(test.getBlue() - current.getBlue(), 2.0D)) / w);
          if (diff < minDiff)
          {
            col = test;
            k2 = k;
            minDiff = diff;
          }
        }
      }
      if (current.getAlpha() >= 128)
      {
        if (k2 < colors.length / 2) {
          simple[j] = Color.WHITE.getRGB();
        } else {
          simple[j] = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
        }
      }
      else {
        simple[j] = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0).getRGB();
      }
    }
    return c.createImage(new MemoryImageSource(width, height, simple, 0, width));
  }

  public static Image shadowColors3(int width, int height, int[] buffer2, Component c, Color[] colors, double[] weights)
  {
    int[] buffer = (int[])buffer2.clone();
    int[] simple = new int[buffer.length];

    double k2 = 0.0D;
    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length; j++)
    {
      int minDiff = 10000000;
      Color current = new Color(buffer[j], true);
      Color col = Color.black;
      for (int k = 0; k < colors.length; k++)
      {
        if (current.getAlpha() == 0)
        {
          col = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0);
          break;
        }
        Color test = colors[k];
        double w = weights[k];
        if (test != null)
        {
          int diff = (int)((Math.pow(test.getRed() - current.getRed(), 2.0D) + Math.pow(test.getGreen() - current.getGreen(), 2.0D) + Math.pow(test.getBlue() - current.getBlue(), 2.0D)) / w);
          if (diff < minDiff)
          {
            col = test;
            minDiff = diff;
            k2 = k;
          }
        }
      }
      int quantErrorR = current.getRed() - col.getRed();
      int quantErrorG = current.getGreen() - col.getGreen();
      int quantErrorB = current.getBlue() - col.getBlue();
      if ((j + 1) % width != 0)
      {
        Color x = new Color(buffer[(j + 1)], true);
        Color y = new Color(Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getRed() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorR * 7 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getGreen() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorG * 7 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getBlue() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorB * 7 / 16, 255)), x.getAlpha());
        buffer[(j + 1)] = y.getRGB();
      }
      if (((j - 1) % width != 0) && (j - 1 + width < buffer.length))
      {
        Color x = new Color(buffer[(j - 1 + width)], true);
        Color y = new Color(Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getRed() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorR * 3 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getGreen() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorG * 3 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getBlue() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorB * 3 / 16, 255)), x.getAlpha());
        buffer[(j - 1 + width)] = y.getRGB();
      }
      if (j + width < buffer.length)
      {
        Color x = new Color(buffer[(j + width)], true);
        Color y = new Color(Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getRed() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorR * 5 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getGreen() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorG * 5 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getBlue() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorB * 5 / 16, 255)), x.getAlpha());
        buffer[(j + width)] = y.getRGB();
      }
      if (((j + 1) % width != 0) && (j + 1 + width < buffer.length))
      {
        Color x = new Color(buffer[(j + 1 + width)], true);
        Color y = new Color(Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getRed() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorR * 1 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getGreen() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorG * 1 / 16, 255)), Math.max(0, Math.min(x.getBlue() + col.getAlpha() / 255 * quantErrorB * 1 / 16, 255)), x.getAlpha());
        buffer[(j + 1 + width)] = y.getRGB();
      }
      if (current.getAlpha() >= 128)
      {
        if (k2 < colors.length / 2) {
          simple[j] = Color.WHITE.getRGB();
        } else {
          simple[j] = Color.BLACK.getRGB();
        }
      }
      else {
        simple[j] = new Color(255, 255, 255, 0).getRGB();
      }
    }
    return c.createImage(new MemoryImageSource(width, height, simple, 0, width));
  }

  public static Image resize(Image i, int[] buffer, Component c, int newDim)
  {
    int h = i.getHeight(c);
    int w = i.getWidth(c);
    if (w < h) {
      return resize(i, buffer, c, newDim, (int)(newDim * 1.0D * w / h));
    }
    return resize(i, buffer, c, (int)(newDim * 1.0D * h / w), newDim);
  }

  public static int getResizedHeight(Image i, Component c, int newDim)
  {
    int h = i.getHeight(c);
    int w = i.getWidth(c);
    if (w < h) {
      return newDim;
    }
    return (int)(newDim * 1.0D * h / w);
  }

  public static int getResizedWidth(Image i, Component c, int newDim)
  {
    int h = i.getHeight(c);
    int w = i.getWidth(c);
    if (w < h) {
      return (int)(newDim * 1.0D * w / h);
    }
    return newDim;
  }

  public static int[] resizebuff(Image i, int[] buffer, Component c, int newDim)
  {
    int h = i.getHeight(c);
    int w = i.getWidth(c);
    if (w < h) {
      return resizebuff(i, buffer, c, newDim, (int)(newDim * 1.0D * w / h));
    }
    return resizebuff(i, buffer, c, (int)(newDim * 1.0D * h / w), newDim);
  }

  public static Image resize2(Image i, int[] buffer, Component c, int newDim)
  {
    int h = i.getHeight(c);
    int w = i.getWidth(c);
    if (w < h) {
      return resize2(i, buffer, c, newDim, (int)(newDim * 1.0D * w / h));
    }
    return resize2(i, buffer, c, (int)(newDim * 1.0D * h / w), newDim);
  }

  public static int[] resize2buff(Image i, int[] buffer, Component c, int newDim)
  {
    int h = i.getHeight(c);
    int w = i.getWidth(c);
    if (w < h) {
      return resize2buff(i, buffer, c, newDim, (int)(newDim * 1.0D * w / h));
    }
    return resize2buff(i, buffer, c, (int)(newDim * 1.0D * h / w), newDim);
  }

  public static Image resize(Image i, int[] buffer, Component c, int newHeight, int newWidth)
  {
    if (newHeight < 2) {
      newHeight = 2;
    }
    if (newWidth < 2) {
      newWidth = 2;
    }
    int height = i.getHeight(c);
    int width = i.getWidth(c);
    if ((height == newHeight) && (width == newWidth)) {
      return i;
    }
    int[] resized = new int[newHeight * newWidth];

    double hRatio = newHeight / height;
    double wRatio = newWidth / width;
    for (int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++)
      {
        int oldX = (int)(x / wRatio);
        int oldY = (int)(y / hRatio);

        resized[(y * newWidth + x)] = buffer[(oldY * width + oldX)];
      }
    }
    return c.createImage(new MemoryImageSource(newWidth, newHeight, resized, 0, newWidth));
  }

  public static int[] resizebuff(Image i, int[] buffer, Component c, int newHeight, int newWidth)
  {
    if (newHeight < 2) {
      newHeight = 2;
    }
    if (newWidth < 2) {
      newWidth = 2;
    }
    int height = i.getHeight(c);
    int width = i.getWidth(c);
    if ((height == newHeight) && (width == newWidth)) {
      return buffer;
    }
    int[] resized = new int[newHeight * newWidth];

    double hRatio = newHeight / height;
    double wRatio = newWidth / width;
    for (int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++)
      {
        int oldX = (int)(x / wRatio);
        int oldY = (int)(y / hRatio);

        resized[(y * newWidth + x)] = buffer[(oldY * width + oldX)];
      }
    }
    return resized;
  }

  public static Image resize2(Image i, int[] buffer, Component c, int newHeight, int newWidth)
  {
    if (newHeight < 2) {
      newHeight = 2;
    }
    if (newWidth < 2) {
      newWidth = 2;
    }
    int height = i.getHeight(c);
    int width = i.getWidth(c);
    if ((height == newHeight) && (width == newWidth)) {
      return i;
    }
    int[] resized = new int[newHeight * newWidth];

    double hRatio = newHeight / height;
    double wRatio = newWidth / width;
    if ((hRatio > 1.0D) || (wRatio > 1.0D)) {
      return resize(i, buffer, c, newHeight, newWidth);
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++)
      {
        int k = 0;
        double oldC = 0.0D;
        double oldRed = 0.0D;
        double oldGreen = 0.0D;
        double oldBlue = 0.0D;
        double oldAlpha = 0.0D;
        for (int q = (int)(x / wRatio); q < (int)((x + 1) / wRatio); q++) {
          for (int j = (int)(y / hRatio); j < (int)((y + 1) / hRatio); j++)
          {
            Color oldColor = new Color(buffer[(j * width + q)], true);
            oldRed = (oldRed * k + oldColor.getRed()) / (k + 1);
            oldGreen = (oldGreen * k + oldColor.getGreen()) / (k + 1);
            oldBlue = (oldBlue * k + oldColor.getBlue()) / (k + 1);
            oldAlpha = (oldAlpha * k + oldColor.getAlpha()) / (k + 1);

            k++;
          }
        }
        resized[(y * newWidth + x)] = new Color((int)oldRed, (int)oldGreen, (int)oldBlue, (int)oldAlpha).getRGB();
      }
    }
    return c.createImage(new MemoryImageSource(newWidth, newHeight, resized, 0, newWidth));
  }

  public static int[] resize2buff(Image i, int[] buffer, Component c, int newHeight, int newWidth)
  {
    if (newHeight < 2) {
      newHeight = 2;
    }
    if (newWidth < 2) {
      newWidth = 2;
    }
    int height = i.getHeight(c);
    int width = i.getWidth(c);
    if ((height == newHeight) && (width == newWidth)) {
      return buffer;
    }
    int[] resized = new int[newHeight * newWidth];

    double hRatio = newHeight / height;
    double wRatio = newWidth / width;
    if ((hRatio > 1.0D) || (wRatio > 1.0D)) {
      return resizebuff(i, buffer, c, newHeight, newWidth);
    }
    for (int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++) {
      for (int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++)
      {
        int k = 0;
        double oldC = 0.0D;
        double oldRed = 0.0D;
        double oldGreen = 0.0D;
        double oldBlue = 0.0D;
        double oldAlpha = 0.0D;
        for (int q = (int)(x / wRatio); q < (int)((x + 1) / wRatio); q++) {
          for (int j = (int)(y / hRatio); j < (int)((y + 1) / hRatio); j++)
          {
            Color oldColor = new Color(buffer[(j * width + q)], true);
            oldRed = (oldRed * k + oldColor.getRed()) / (k + 1);
            oldGreen = (oldGreen * k + oldColor.getGreen()) / (k + 1);
            oldBlue = (oldBlue * k + oldColor.getBlue()) / (k + 1);
            oldAlpha = (oldAlpha * k + oldColor.getAlpha()) / (k + 1);

            k++;
          }
        }
        resized[(y * newWidth + x)] = new Color((int)oldRed, (int)oldGreen, (int)oldBlue, (int)oldAlpha).getRGB();
      }
    }
    return resized;
  }

  public static int[] countColors(int[] buffer, Component c, Color[] colors)
  {
    int[] count = new int[colors.length];
    for (int k = 0; k < count.length; k++) {
      count[k] = 0;
    }
    Color col = Color.BLACK;
    for (int j = 0; j < buffer.length; j++)
    {
      col = new Color(buffer[j]);
      for (int k = 0; k < colors.length; k++) {
        if ((colors[k] != null) && (colors[k].getRGB() == col.getRGB())) {
          count[k] += 1;
        }
      }
    }
    return count;
  }
```

(Had to cut it off b/c of character limit)

EDIT: Turns out the first error doesn't matter. The program tries to run textures from a separate file. If it isn't found, it skips it.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: fix finding the file and the rest may work

Answer (score 0):

Addressing your second issue with the stack trace:

This line is your issue:
`resized[(y * newWidth + x)] = buffer[(oldY * width + oldX)];`

Specifically this part `resized[(y * newWidth + x)]` because `[y * newWidth + x]` can be far bigger than what `resized` allows.

---

Let's assume the image is 100x50 (WxH), this means that `int[] resized = new int[newHeight * newWidth];` will create a new array that is 5000 long.

However the for loops will create something much higher:

`for (int y = 0; y < newHeight; y++)` in this instance `y` will go as high as `newHeight` or 100

vfor (int x = 0; x < newWidth; x++)`in this instance`y`will go as high as`newWidth` or 50

So:

`resized[(y * newWidth + x)] = something;` will be an issue because `100 * 100 + 50` can be as large as 10050, that is far bigger than 5000.

The solution is to make a larger `resized` array, or to rethink your for loops.